# What's the background music at 04:45 called?

Tags: identify-this-song

Can't recollect what it was called

Comment: While identification questions have been allowed in the past, they are currently off-topic. More detail about why these questions are off-topic can be found [on meta](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-identify-question-question-time-for-a-trial-separation).